# Is each object's instance variable unique in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I read somewhere that each object's instance variables are unique.

I'm not sure how to make sense of that statement.  Can someone explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that it means that two instances of the same class have their own, unshared instance variables, even though they are called the same thing.

```
class Dog
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

dog1 = Dog.new('Spot')
dog2 = Dot.new('Rover')

dog1.instance_variable_get "@name" # "Spot"
dog2.instance_variable_get "@name" # "Rover"
```

Comment: What if dog2 = Dog.new('Spot'), would both dog (dog1 and dog2) objects have instance variables pointing to the same "Spot" string object?  If not, then I think this answers the question.

Comment: Each string object is a separate object -- just check "foo".object_id == "foo".object_id (false! or use the .equal? method).  Contrast this with symbols, which are interned -- every occurrence of :foo points to exactly the same space in memory.

Comment: @Nathan: That would be true for a `Symbol`, like `:spot`, but not for `String` like Max said.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in ruby, unlike variables in a language like JavaScript, are not globally scoped. As an example, if you do this in irb:

```
1.9.3-p125 :036 > def myMethod
1.9.3-p125 :037?>   my_variable = 12
1.9.3-p125 :038?>   end
 => nil 
1.9.3-p125 :039 > myMethod
 => 12 
1.9.3-p125 :040 > my_variable
NameError: undefined local variable or method `my_variable' for main:Object
    from (irb):40
    from /Users/Thoughtworks/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

The variable my_variable doesn't exist outside the method, because it is no longer in scope. I can also do this:

```
1.9.3-p125 :057 > my_variable = 13
 => 13 
1.9.3-p125 :058 > myMethod
 => 12 
1.9.3-p125 :059 > my_variable
 => 13
```

In this case, even though I've named my_variable in the main scope, there is a different variable, also named my_variable, that exists in the scope of the method myMethod. So assigning 12 to my_variable in the scope of myMethod doesn't change the variable in the main scope, and the main variable doesn't exist in the method scope.

For a class, if I write this:

```
class Dog
  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

spot = Dog.new(:spot)
fido = Dog.new(:spot)
```

then both `spot.name` and `fido.name` point to the same thing--the symbol `:spot`. But if I then do this:

```
spot.name = "spot"
```

then `fido.name` will still be `:spot`, and `spot.name` will be `"spot"`. The two `@name` instance variables have nothing to with each other, if they point to the same value than this is mere coincidence.

So the idea that each objects instance variables are unique doesn't mean that they can't reference the same thing, it means that they are **distinct** from each other, regardless of what they reference.